# Firebase Realtime - Cloud functions TypeError: Cannot read property 'Male' of null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, counter

I've created and successfully deployed a function that will keep up with counters in my database. The counters represent different data values and are meant to increment when a new user is created on a successful web application submission to the database. My data is successfully submitted to my database, but my cloud function returns an error in my logs:

[image]

The "Male" part is one of the the options from my form submission, where the user chooses from a drop-down list of gender options. This makes me think that, at the very least, the value is being received by the function. But where is the null coming from? All of the data from the submission is successfully stored in the database as far as I can tell.

I'm currently testing my function on "gender" before expanding to the other fields in my form. My cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.onUserCreate = functions.database
.ref('/students/{studentID}/')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const userData = snapshot.val();

    const countersRef = admin.database().ref('/counters/');
    return countersRef.transaction(currentData => {
        currentData[userData.gender] = (currentData[userData.gender] || 0) + 1;
        return currentData;
    });

});
```

And for reference, my database has the following structure:
[image]

But my counter for "Male" is still at zero:

[image]

**EDIT**:

I logged `console.log(countersRef)`, `console.log(userData)`, and `console.log(currentData)`, and now I get the following:

The first returned a lot of information about my database. The second:

```
{ afterGrad: 'Masters',
  elaborate: '',
  firstName: 'test',
  gender: 'Male',
  gradDate: '2014',
  hometown: 'home',
  lastName: 'user',
  program: 'Undergraduate',
  race: 'American Indian or Alaska Native',
  timeToComplete: '2 years' }
```

But now, I get this error for my log of the currentData:

[image]

Comment: Please add the results of `console.log(countersRef)`, `console.log(userData)` and `console.log(currentData)` inside the transaction.

Comment: I've added the results of the console logs to my original post.

Comment: You are not referencing the gender --> const countersRef = admin.database().ref('/counters/${userData.gender}');  then change the rest accordingly.  Use backtick in there i don't why they don't show.